# Как проверить есть ли у юзера telegram premium Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Подскажите как проверить есть ли премиум у пользователя или нет.
Не могу найти. Я делаю бота на aiogram 2 и вроде там не поддерживается это, поправьте если не прав, поэтому хотелось бы узнать как прописать это самому если возможно

Comment: в бот апи есть, в aiogram 2 нет. можно это как то прописать?

Answer (score 0):

Вроде как можно так

```
async def func_name(message: types.Message):
    print(message.from_user.is_premium)
```

Comment: Пробовал, выдает такую ошибку:
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'is_premium'

Comment: @kridti какая у вас конкретно версия aiogram?

Comment: У меня 2.23.1 и всё работает

Comment: aiogram==2.23.1

Comment: @kridti странно, попробуйте переустановить его, ибо у меня все ок